# como refrescar un datatable de primefaces despues de un click?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, modal, datatable

Tengo el siguiente form

```
<h:form id="form">
  <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-clock" styleClass="element-button green hacia-izquierda" style="margin-right: 5em; margin-top: -1em;" value="Horario" update=":form:horario" oncomplete="PF('modalHorario').show();">
  </p:commandButton>
  <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
  <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-folder-open" styleClass="element-button green hacia-derecha" style="margin-right: 95em; margin-top: -1em;" value="Historial" update="form2,form3">
    <p:ajax listener="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.obtieneHistorialHorarios()}" update=":form3:fieldset" />
  </p:commandButton>
  <!--Modal que muestra el formulario para cambia el horario-->
  <p:dialog header="Establecer Nuevo  Horario" id="horario" widgetVar="modalHorario" modal="true" height="410" width="600px">

    <h:outputLabel value="Horario" />
    <p:spacer width="35" height="1" />
    <p:selectOneMenu autoWidth="false" style="width:400px" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.horarios.cveIdHorario}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{HorariosComponent.listHorarioss()}" var="horario" itemValue="#{horario.cveIdHorario}" itemLabel="#{horario.horarioEntrada} a #{horario.horarioSalida} Tolerancia #{horario.toleranciaRetardo} Falta #{horario.toleranciaFalta} ">
      </f:selectItems>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br></br>
    <h:outputLabel value="Ubicación" />
    <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
    <p:selectOneMenu autoWidth="false" style="width:400px" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.unidadAdministrativa.cveIdUnidadAdmin}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{UnidadAdministrativaComponent.listUnidadAdministrativas()}" var="ubicacion" itemValue="#{ubicacion.cveIdUnidadAdmin}" itemLabel="#{ubicacion.cveIdUnidadAdmin} - #{ubicacion.desUnidadAdministrativa}">
      </f:selectItems>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <h:outputLabel value="Fec.Inicio" />
    <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
    <p:calendar id="popup" placeholder="Fecha Inicio" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecInicioNivel}" />
    <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Fec.Fin" />
    <p:spacer width="25" height="1" />
    <p:calendar id="popup3" placeholder="Fecha Fin" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel}" rendered="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.fechaValida(NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel)}">

    </p:calendar>
    <p:calendar id="popup4" placeholder="Fecha Fin" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.fechaFinNivel2}" rendered="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.fechaValida(NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel) eq false}">

    </p:calendar>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <h:outputLabel value="Obs." />
    <p:spacer width="50" height="1" />
    <p:inputText placeholder="Observaciones" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.observaciones}" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaLunes}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Lunes" />
    <p:spacer width="10" height="1" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaMartes}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Martes" />
    <p:spacer width="10" height="1" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaMiercoles}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Miercoles" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaJueves}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Jueves" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaViernes}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Viernes" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaSabado}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Sabado" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaDomingo}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Domingo" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaFestivo}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Festivo" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checa}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Debe registrar E/S en Biometrico" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.esComision}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Comisión" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkEspecial" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.aplicaHorarioEspecial}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Horario Especial" />
    <p:tooltip id="toolTipFocus" for="checkEspecial" value="Horario para mamá" position="right" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-times" value="Cancelar" styleClass="element-button red hacia-izquierda" style="margin-right: 5em; margin-top: 1em;" oncomplete="PF('modalHorario').hide();">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-save" styleClass="element-button blue hacia-derecha" style="margin-right: 15em; margin-top: 1em;" value="Guardar" process="@form" action="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.saveNivelesPersona()}" oncomplete="PF('modalHorario').hide();"
      update=":form2:horarios1">

    </p:commandButton>
  </p:dialog>


</h:form>
```

El cual contiene un **p:dialog**, y ya lleno todos los campos y doy en el boton guardar que esta adentro del modal, el cual debe de actualizar una tabla
pero no lo hace hasta que refresque la pagina

la tabla es esta, la cual en una columna tiene una accion de editar
y abre otro modal, que contiene casi lo mismo que el anterior

```
<h:form id="form2">

  <p:dataTable id="horarios1" var="consultaHorario" rendered="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.muestraHistorial}" style="max-width:2000px;max-height:770px;" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.listNivelesPersona2}">

    <p:column headerText="Ubi" style="width: 20px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.unidadAdministrativa.cveIdUnidadAdmin}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Vigencia" style="width: 150px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecInicioNivel}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
      </h:outputText> -
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecFinNivel}" rendered="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.fechaValida(consultaHorario.fecFinNivel)}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
      </h:outputText>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Horario" style="width: 70px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.horarios.horarioEntrada} - #{consultaHorario.horarios.horarioSalida}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Tol." style="width: 20px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.horarios.toleranciaRetardo}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Max. Falta" style="width: 20px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.horarios.toleranciaFalta}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Checa" style="width: 30px;">

      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-check" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checa eq true}" />
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-close" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checa eq false}" />

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Lunes" style="width: 30px;">
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-check" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaLunes eq true}" />
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-close" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaLunes eq false}" />

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Martes" style="width: 30px;">
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-check" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaMartes eq true}" />
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-close" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaMartes eq false}" />

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Miércoles" style="width: 45px;">
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-check" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaMiercoles eq true}" />
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-close" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaMiercoles eq false}" />

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Jueves" style="width: 30px;">
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-check" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaJueves eq true}" />
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-close" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaJueves eq false}" />

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Viernes" style="width: 30px;">
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-check" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaViernes eq true}" />
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-close" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaViernes eq false}" />

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Sábado" style="width: 30px;">
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-check" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaSabado eq true}" />
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-close" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaSabado eq false}" />

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Domingo" style="width: 15x;">
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-check" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaDomingo eq true}" />
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-close" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaDomingo eq false}" />

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Festivo" style="width: 30px;">
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-check" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaFestivo eq true}" />
      <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-close" rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaFestivo eq false}" />

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Observaciones" style="width: 150px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.observaciones}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Acción" style="width: 30px;">
      <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-edit" update=":form2:modalEditar" title="Editar" oncomplete="PF('modalEditar').show()" styleClass="element-button green" style="margin-right: 15em;">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{consultaHorario}" target="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona}" />

      </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
  <!--Modal para editar el horario-->
  <p:dialog header="Editar Horario" id="modalEditar" widgetVar="modalEditar" modal="true" height="410" width="600px">

    <h:outputLabel value="Horario" />
    <p:spacer width="35" height="1" />
    <p:selectOneMenu autoWidth="false" style="width:400px" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.horarios.cveIdHorario}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{HorariosComponent.listHorarioss()}" var="horario" itemValue="#{horario.cveIdHorario}" itemLabel="#{horario.horarioEntrada} a #{horario.horarioSalida} Tolerancia #{horario.toleranciaRetardo} Falta #{horario.toleranciaFalta} ">
      </f:selectItems>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br></br>
    <h:outputLabel value="Ubicación" />
    <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
    <p:selectOneMenu autoWidth="false" style="width:400px" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.unidadAdministrativa.cveIdUnidadAdmin}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{UnidadAdministrativaComponent.listUnidadAdministrativas()}" var="ubicacion" itemValue="#{ubicacion.cveIdUnidadAdmin}" itemLabel="#{ubicacion.cveIdUnidadAdmin} - #{ubicacion.desUnidadAdministrativa}">
      </f:selectItems>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <h:outputLabel value="Fec.Inicio" />
    <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
    <p:calendar id="popup" placeholder="Fecha Inicio" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecInicioNivel}" />
    <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Fec.Fin" />
    <p:spacer width="25" height="1" />
    <p:calendar id="popup1" placeholder="Fecha Fin" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel}" rendered="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.fechaValida(NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel)}">

    </p:calendar>
    <p:calendar id="popup2" placeholder="Fecha Fin" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.fechaFinNivel1}" rendered="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.fechaValida(NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.fecFinNivel) eq false}">

    </p:calendar>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <h:outputLabel value="Obs." />
    <p:spacer width="50" height="1" />
    <p:inputText placeholder="Observaciones" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.observaciones}" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaLunes}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Lunes" />
    <p:spacer width="10" height="1" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaMartes}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Martes" />
    <p:spacer width="10" height="1" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaMiercoles}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Miercoles" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaJueves}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Jueves" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaViernes}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Viernes" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaSabado}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Sabado" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaDomingo}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Domingo" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checaFestivo}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Festivo" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.nivelespersona.checa}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Debe registrar E/S en Biometrico" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.esComision}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Comisión" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkEspecial" value="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.aplicaHorarioEspecial}" />
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Horario Especial" />
    <p:tooltip id="toolTipFocus" for="checkEspecial" value="Horario para mamá" position="right" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-times" value="Cancelar" styleClass="element-button red hacia-izquierda" style="margin-right: 5em; margin-top: 1em;" oncomplete="PF('modalEditar').hide();">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:spacer width="20" height="1" />
    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-save" styleClass="element-button blue hacia-derecha" style="margin-right: 15em; margin-top: 1em;" value="Guardar" process="@form" action="#{NivelesPersonaComponent.saveActualizarNivelesPersona()}" oncomplete="PF('modalEditar').hide();"
      update=":form2:horarios1,:form:horario,:form4:fielset1">


    </p:commandButton>
  </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

En ese modal de editar si edito un registro y le doy en guardar si aparece en automatico el cambio en la tabla, pero no lo hace cuando agregao cosas en el primer modal hasta que recargo la pagina

Comment: Has probado usar update="@form" en el boton donde necesitas que te actualice

Comment: ya, pero no lo hace, lo que sucede es que si actualiza pero sobre el ultimo registro que tengo, y ya cuando recargo la pagina ya lo agrega bien

Comment: Si he tenido ese mismo problema algunas veces he tenido que refrescar la página para que funcione y otras veces he pedido al usuario que realice la busqueda nuevamente

Comment: Prueba con @all aunque no es recomendable hacerlo así

Comment: ¿Cuando presionas el botón de guardar, vuelves a cargar el listado del `dataTable`?

Comment: @Garrizano, ese fue mi problema, no estaba cargando de nuevo la lista

Comment: cómo se haría eso d cargar de nuevo la lista?